# Write rows from Postgres Table into a CSV file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

**I want to writerows to the given NAS(mnt) folder from a postgres table, but only after performing some data hygine checks**

*Below is the actual code which is working, but it only selects columns from the table and saves the data into a .txt file*

```py
import os
import psycopg2
import time
import pandas as pd

# File path and name.
filePath = '/mnt/nasdatavant/datavant/covid_implementation/postgres_files/'
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%-H%M%S")
fileName = 'covid-' + timestr + '.txt'

# Database connection variable.
connect = None

# Check if the file path exists.
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    connect = psycopg2.connect(<connection_details_here>)
    with connect.cursor() as cursor:
        sqlSelect = "select patnt_last_nm as cust_last_nm, \
                     patnt_frst_nm as cust_frst_nm, \
                     date(patnt_brth_dt) as cust_brth_dt, \
                     patnt_gendr_cd as cust_gendr_cd, \
                     patnt_postl_cd as cust_postl_cd, \
                     indiv_entpr_id from datavant_o.covid_patnt_registry"
        cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        print(results)
        headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
        csvFile = csv.writer(open(filePath + fileName, 'w', newline=''),
                                delimiter='|', lineterminator='\r\n', escapechar='\\')
        csvFile.writerow(headers)
        csvFile.writerows(results)
        connect.commit()
        connect.close()
else:
        print("File path does not exist.")
```

Note: when i say print(results) it yields a list of tuples
eg:

```
[('TOBY', 'MICHEAL', datetime.date(1986, 8, 23), 'M', '06472', '872956'), 
('CARLIE', 'NAHLA', datetime.date(1979, 9, 29),..etc]
```

so to yield a dataframe i wrote
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

**What i actually want now is to add data hygiene checks like below before writing into a .txt file**

what i tried:

```py
       csvFile = csv.writer(open(filePath + fileName, 'w', newline=''),
                                delimiter='|', lineterminator='\r\n', escapechar='\\')
        df = pd.DataFrame(results)
        print(df)
        df = df.dropna(axis=0)
        df = df.loc[
                  (df[0].astype('str').str.len()>1) & (df[1].astype('str').str.len()>1) &
                  (df[4].astype('str').str.len()>4) & (df[4].astype('str').str.len()<8)]
        csvFile.writerow(headers)
        csvFile.writerows(df)
```

error i got:

```
error: 
csvFile.writerows(df)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
```

Final expected output(in .txt file):

```
cust_last_nm|cust_frst_nm|cust_brth_dt|cust_gendr_cd|cust_postl_cd|indiv_entpr_id
TOBY|MICHEAL|1986-08-23|M|06472|872956
CARLIE|NAHLA|1979-09-29|F|06757|499666 …etc
```

i need some help to solve this scenario (new to pandas) thanks ahead.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64712936/12350326 , modify a bit to satisfy your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import psycopg2
import time
import pandas as pd

# File path and name.
filePath = '/mnt/nasdatavant/datavant/covid_implementation/postgres_files/'
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%-H%M%S")
fileName = 'covid-' + timestr + '.csv'

# Check if the file path exists.
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    connect = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres")
    with connect.cursor() as cursor:

        # create test table
        cursor.execute("create table if not exists test_table (test_column int)")
        cursor.execute("insert into test_table (test_column) values (10);")

        # query and import as Dataframe
        df = pd.read_sql("select * from test_table", connect)

        # add here your cleaning operations
        df = df.dropna(axis=0)

        # export
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(filePath, fileName), index=False)

        connect.commit()
        connect.close()
else:
    print("File path does not exist.")
```